# Raphael: How to unbind the mousemove function on mouseup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am drawing a line with Raphael. I have a mousedown event where I store the starting position. While the mouse is down, if the user moves it, I have a mousemove event where I keep drawing the line as the mouse moves.

Now when the mouse button is released, the line should stop. This does not happen and line keeps going on if the mouse moves even though button is released. This line must stop on mouseup. If the user does mousedown again, it should begin a new line.

I have tried many combinations with the unmouse* events, but I am missing something here.

JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/zaphod013/P33FA/5/

(This is my first date with JS/Raphael. So if you think I am totally off track here, please tell me so)

```
var g_masterPaper;
var g_startX;
var g_startY;
var g_line;

function initDrawing() {
    g_masterPaper = Raphael(10,10,700,500);

    var masterBackground = g_masterPaper.rect(10,10,600,400);
    masterBackground.attr("fill", "#eee");

    var drawit = function(event) {
        x = event.pageX - 10;
        y = event.pageY - 10;
        var linepath = ("M"+g_startX+" "+g_startY+" L"+x+" "+y);
        g_line.attr("path", linepath);
    };

    var startit = function (event) {
        g_startX = event.pageX - 10;
        g_startY = event.pageY - 10;
        g_line = g_masterPaper.path("M"+g_startX+" "+g_startY+" L"+g_startX+" "+g_startY);
        masterBackground.mousemove(drawit);
    };

    masterBackground.mousedown(startit);
    masterBackground.mouseup(function (event) {
        this.unmousedown(startit);
        this.unmousemove(drawit);
    });

    return g_masterPaper;
}

window.onload = function () {
var paper=initDrawing();
paper.text(15,475,'Use your mouse to draw.').attr({fill:'#ff0000', 'font-size':24, 'stroke-width':1,'text-anchor':'start' });      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on track and mostly looks fine, I would possibly just simplify your handlers, and not keep removing/adding them, it keeps handlers hard to track and debug. So I would just have one handler for down/up/move...

Edit:
[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/P33FA/6/) or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P33FA/7/) which gets around other elements capturing the mouseup event and stopping it working properly.

```
var drawit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    x = event.pageX - 10;
    y = event.pageY - 10;
    var linepath = ("M"+g_startX+" "+g_startY+" L"+x+" "+y);
    if( g_line ) { g_line.attr("path", linepath) };
};

var startit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    g_startX = event.pageX - 10;
    g_startY = event.pageY - 10;
    g_line = g_masterPaper.path("M"+g_startX+" "+g_startY+" L"+g_startX+" "+g_startY);
};

var finish = function ( event ) {
    g_line = '';
}
```

Comment: I yet think there is something I am missing in the handlers. The line should be drawn with mousemove only while the mousebutton is down. Once I release the button, the line should stop drawing. Then if I press the mouse button again, a new line should be drawn. Right now, whether the mouse button is up or down, the line keeps getting drawn.

Comment: Apologies, I think there was a bug, it works in Chrome, but mouseup doesn't work in FFX. I think whats happening is that mouseup won't work properly as its drawing a line which captures the mouseup event (as its over the rect). You could use jquery to attach a handler like http://jsfiddle.net/P33FA/7/ to get around the problem is possibly the simplest way. You may just need to adjust the cursor offset as I popped it in a div and added the handler to that.

Comment: Works! Thanks. I see that you are binding the functions to the div events instead of element events. Can you please explain what you mean by "mouseup won't work properly as its drawing a line which captures the mouseup event (as its over the rect)"?

Comment: Initially mouseup is bound to the rect, however once we draw the line, the line is now 'inbetween' the mouse cursor and the rect (as we've placed it direct under the mouse, so the only mouseup event could come from the 'line' element). Another solution could be to offset the line slightly maybe, but that probably doesn't look so good. Or we could bind a mouseup handler to the line element each time we create it and delete it after, but I think thats messy also.